# How to Loop and Replace Characters inside an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/xLea235h/) and let me know how I can loop through and element like `<pre>` and replace all `<` and `>` with some new characters like:

```
.replace("<", "1");
.replace(">", "2");
```

if we have a `<pre>` like

```
<pre>
    < This is a test < which must > replace >
</pre>
```

Thanks

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xLea235h/1/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) using an [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```js
$('pre').text(function(i, text){
    return text.replace(/</g, '1').replace(/>/g, '2')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
    < This is a test < which must > replace >
</pre>
```

Comment: just one question? is this going to work in case of having several `<pre>` in the page?

Comment: @user3649067 contents of each `pre` will be replaced with the same logic

Answer (score 0):

may be like

```js
var test = $("pre").text();

var k = test.split("<").join(1).split(">").join(2);

alert(k);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>< This is a test < which must > replace ></pre>
```

reference : [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)